# Feedback on my document management system

Tags: data-tables, html5

I've created a document management system and want to make the table look more stylish.

https://codepen.io/reonLOW/pen/abbbMrZ

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well so my subjective suggest to improve it:

**1. Column Sorting** - interface can  can further emphasize the possibility of sorting based on columns (I recommend reading about the one color interaction of the active element)

**2.Search** - the search engine could be on the left side and work dynamically

**3.ID Column** - let's think if it is necessary for the user or does it just cause unnecessary information chaos?

**4. Actions** - You could hide them in one action - but is it necessary?

**5. Data** - In the case of more data, I think that filtering mechanisms could be useful (e.g. by version or department)